# How to pull (fetch) data from a sheet or an object from QlikSense?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, qliksense

My company is using QlikSense 3.0 as a backbone for all their Business Intelligence activities. As it turns out one of the graphs (HeatMap) is built using Angular and we want to keep the same view. I was hoping if there is a way we can fetch data from the QlikSense HeatMap graph and just use the same data to render the existing view.

> Can anyone help me understand how to fetch data from existing graphs in QlikSense using any API?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at the [Qlik Sense Engine API documentations](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/3.1/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/introducing-engine-API.htm)

You can access the Engine via Java Script/Node JS or ASP.NET

If you want to get the data outside QS then Node JS/.NET are you options (i think someone build and Python library but its 3rd party one)